# What is wrong with this PIC pin change detection?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, c

I have two PIC18F4620 connected via SPI + Slave Select + additional IRQ line. Both controllers are driven from the same crystal oscillator using the same clock settings. The master sends one byte and then waits until the slave toggles that additional IRQ line. The duration of the toggling is 4 instruction cycles. All the edges look good on the scope and SPI communication works properly, except for the detection of the toggling (`while(!PORTBbits.RB1);`).

This is my SPI sending code:

```
    while (spi_out_msg_buffer.write_cursor > spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor)
    {
        DisableInterrupts;
        SSPBUF = spi_out_msg_buffer.data[spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor];
        LATBbits.LATB0 = 1;
        while(!PORTBbits.RB1); // wait for toggle on IRQ line
        LATBbits.LATB0 = 0;
        EnableInterrupts;
        spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor++;
    }
```

The `while(!PORTBbits.RB1);` is translated into two instructions:

```
BTFSS PORTB, 1, ACCESS
BRA 0x188
```

I insterted that `B0` line for debugging purposes, you can see it at the very bottom of this timing diagram:

[image: timing]

You can see the toggling of the IRQ line (second from the bottom) and how it goes undetected, because the `B0` debugging line stays high. When I stop the execution via ICD it hangs inside the `while`.
It is worth to mention that it usually works for a few bytes and then stops, as you can see here:

[image: whole timing]

I measured that the pulse is actually 4 instruction cycles (= 16 PLL cycles = 4 clock cycles) long:

[image: pulse length]

I think that should be sufficient for the pulse to be detected. Even if the first BTFSS misses it because the port is sampled at the beginning of the instruction cycle, then the second one should get it:

[image: even more timing]

10 MHz -> PLL -> 40 MHz -> 10 M instructions per second -> 100 ns per instruction.

Shouldn't that be long enough to exit the `while`?

Comment: check your assembly code, it could easily be more then 4 instructions, although in this case it could be less.

Comment: Why not use the level-change facility of a number of the PIC's IO lines?  This updates a flag (and/or triggers an interrupt) when the value on the pin changes.  This in independent of the instruction clock and should make your system more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual reason was me being a moron. My `DisableInterrupts` macro did `INTCONbits.GIE=1`.

I found this by toggling a pin during busy waiting:

```
while(!PORTBbits.RB1)
{
    LATBbits.LATB0 = 0;
    LATBbits.LATB0 = 1;
}
```

I noticed that the toggling stopped in regular intervals and when the notification pulse falls into one of these windows, it goes unnoticed.

[image]

Comment: None of you could know that, nevertheless +1 for both your answers for pointing me to the cycle count and the pinchange interrupt.

Answer (score 6):

You're using a compiler, so you have no idea how many cycles that polling loop takes.  In assembler you could get it down to 3 cycles, but you gave up the right to count cycles when you wrote the code in a high level language.

However, the real problem is the overall approach.  Asking the code to catch a short glitch is not a good idea.  Even if you could guarantee the loop time is less than the glitch time, you can now not turn on interrupts during the wait.  This may present architectural problems later.

A much better idea is to use the hardware you already have to catch the glitch, then have the firmware check that hardware.  The simplest would be to wire the glitch into one of the INTx lines, then look for the INTxIF flag.  Change detect pins would also work, but keep in mind the flag gets set on both edges and you have to clear the mismatch to clear the condition.

Comment: You can still *count* cycles when you're using a high-level language, it just takes some digging.  I agree, though, using hardware would be a better way overall.

Comment: @Kevin: You can count cycles with some digging, but the answer isn't very meaningful.  It will tell you only what that version of the compiler at that optimization setting and other possibly non-obvious parameters does.  If you need to guarantee the number of cycles in a loop, you have to disable interrupts and write it in assembler.

Comment: I disabled interrupts as you can see in the code and I copied the assembly snippet in the question right from the disassembly, so that is exactly what gets executed on the PIC, isn't it?

Comment: I already deliberately used pin B1 for the IRQ line, so indeed I can take advantage of its interrupt capability. However, I am very curious why it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 5):

The last instruction it's an unconditional branch, right? Usually branches and memory accesses (made on the first instruction, right?) take about 2-3x more time to execute, so in you're case those instructions could take about 16 cycles to execute, which is 400ns (on the best case scenario).

Comment: Can you give more information about how the OP(original poster) might go about finding this out. How can you get around this? Lets solve a problem! I pointed out in my comment they should check their assembly code.

Comment: I'm not a PIC18 expert, but according to [this](http://www.ermicro.com/blog/?p=1846) site you have a flag that's updated when the SPI send/receive operation ends. Try replacing that line for `while(!SSPSTATbits.BF);`.

Comment: Oh, indeed I was unaware of the fact that the BRA takes two instruction cycles, but still 400 ns should be sufficient, or not? I updated the question with how I imagine the worst case.

Comment: @AndreKR: PORTB it's an address right? If it is then BRFSS will probably take the same time as the branch to complete (because the MCU have to load the value on PORTB to a register). Why don't you try my suggestion on the comment above, wich I believe it's the same of @MattJenkins on the first answer?

Comment: From the datasheet: *All single-word instructions are executed in a single instruction cycle, unless a conditional test is true or the program counter is changed as a result of the instruction. In these cases, the execution takes two instruction cycles, with the additional instruction cycle(s) executed as a NOP.* Your suggestion has nothing to do with my problem. MattJenkins' is the same as Olin's suggestion, please see my comment there.

Comment: @AndreKR: see Table 24-2 of [the manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39626e.pdf)

Comment: You mean the "1 (2 or 3) cycles" of the BTFSS? That is 1 cycle if the condition is not met (bit is not set), 2 cycles *if* and only if the bit is set so it has to skip and 3 cycles to skip over a two-word instruction (which BRA is not).

Comment: @AndreKR: Sorry I've misread it I thought that when the condition is not met he have to skip the next instruction. While I gave a look at that manual I saw some assembly code to write to SPIbuf, you could take a look.

Comment: No problem, actually they have an instruction for that but I didn't use that. Anyway, this isn't at all about SPI, maybe I should have never mentioned SPI.